# What happened to Neville on his first broom flight?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*, during the first broom-flying class for the first years, Neville's broom takes him on a wild ride.

At first, Madame Hooch seems prepared for this, and points her wand at Neville (presumably to take control and help him back to ground). But she has to jump out of the way and fails at whatever she was trying to do. He ends up breaking his arm, but could easily have been killed if he hadn't caught on a statue that slowed his fall.

**What happened?**

Does this insane lack of control just happen sometimes with new broom riders? And Madame Hooch was just unprepared for the level of chaos that Neville could cause?

Or was Neville's broom defective in some way? Or maybe even cursed?

Comment: Is it possible that Malfoy cursed the broom?

Comment: It seems beyond Draco's skill level, but it could be possible. With some evidence, that would be a valid answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In the book](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/first-flying-lesson), the Neville is too terrified to control his broom properly.  Like many things in the wizarding world (photographs, for example), the brooms seem to have a certain anima and personality to them.  The school brooms are well known to be particularly cheap and thus terrible to control.

> Harry had heard Fred and George Weasley complain about the school brooms, saying that some of them started to vibrate if you flew too high, or always flew slightly to the left.
>
> ...
>
> Perhaps brooms, like horses, could tell when you were afraid, thought Harry; there was a quaver in Neville’s voice that said only too clearly that he wanted to keep his feet on the ground.

Neville, feeling very uncomfortable with the flying lesson, takes off too early and too hard.

> But Neville, nervous and jumpy and frightened of being left on the ground, pushed off hard before the whistle had touched Madam Hooch’s lips.
>
> ‘Come back, boy!’ she shouted, but Neville was rising straight up like a cork shot out of a bottle – twelve feet – twenty feet. Harry saw his scared white face look down at the ground falling away, saw him gasp, slip sideways off the broom and –
>
> WHAM – a thud and a nasty crack and Neville lay, face down, on the grass in a heap. His broomstick was still rising higher and higher and started to drift lazily towards the Forbidden Forest and out of sight.

It sounds like he fell from a height of about twenty feet—something that is likely to be uncomfortable but not fatal.  In fact, he suffers a wrist injury, but that is taken care of without too much difficulty.  Madame Hooch is not happy with the situation, but she has it well in hand.

> Madam Hooch was bending over Neville, her face as white as his.
>
> ‘Broken wrist,’ Harry heard her mutter. ‘Come on, boy — it’s all right, up you get.’

Comment: I don't think  Madame Hooch had it well in hand. He might have fallen head first and broken his neck. Falling head first is even likely if you lose your balance and try to cling to the broom with your legs. Her lessons assume that they are already able to control a broom and just need practice.

Comment: @ralfriedl in the books, wizards are generally shown as far more resistant to physical injury than one would expect, and far more cavalier about the potential of it. If I recall correctly, one of the Gryffindors relates a story about being tested for wizards as an infant by being dropped out a window as an infant by a relative, and bouncing.

Comment: @notovny: I believe that was Neville, and that he was much older than an infant, but still a child (specifically, his toad, Trevor, was bought by his Uncle as a reward for this "feat", IIRC). That said, in general, the wizarding world seems to be "behind the times" a bit, and their relative lack of regard for potentially dangerous situations seems to be reflective of that: cf. "latchkey kids" riding on bicycles for hours without helmets or supervision for hours, possibly after dark. That wouldn't really fly today, at least where I am from...